# Compiler showing package doesn't exist even if it's shown in my IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, build, package

I tried to build a **Java** application on a **Linux** machine by using

```
ant rebuild content
```

But this message appeared on command prompt :

> Package com.dir1.dir2 doesn't exist import com.dir1.dir2.File

So I clicked on `File2` from the import statement while pressing **Ctrl** button in **IntelliJ IDEA**, which showed me that `com.dir1.dir2.File` does exist.

So can someone please tell my why is this message being shown?

Comment: Where (path) did you execute the script ? Maybe ant need to be done at another place, so where you did `ant rebuild content` ant cannot see the packages

Comment: @NathaëlNoguès from the place where my build.xml file exists

Comment: Ok, I cannot help you more I think, but check that your build.xml is at the right place (Because IntelliJ uses his own paths to execute his classes), I let others help you ;)